# Is there any way to use AddSingleton in ApplicationInitialization under the ABP framework?

Tags: c#, .net-core, abp

I'm using the ABP framework, and want to register a singleton class for global use. but it needs some other class. So I want the OnApplicationInitialization function to register it.

```cs
 public override void OnApplicationInitialization(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
{
     var settingManager = context.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISettingManager>();
     var cloudStorageProviderManager = context.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISlideCloudStorageProviderManager>();
      var cloudProvider = await settingManager.GetOrNullGlobalAsync(CloudStorageSettings.CloudProvider);
      var slideCloudStorage = cloudStorageProviderManager.Resolve(cloudProvider);

      // how to  register slideCloudStorage.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

## Is there any way to register a singleton class that needs some other class? (Problem X)

Yes, you can use `AddSingleton` in `ConfigureServices` with a function as an implementation factory.

```cs
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    context.Services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider =>
    {
        var settingManager = serviceProvider.GetService<ISettingManager>();
        var cloudStorageProviderManager = serviceProvider.GetService<ISlideCloudStorageProviderManager>();
        var cloudProvider = settingManager.GetOrNullGlobal(CloudStorageSettings.CloudProvider);
        return cloudStorageProviderManager.Resolve(cloudProvider);
    });
}
```

## Is there any way to use AddSingleton in ApplicationInitialization under ABP framework? (Solution Y)

No, there is no supported way.